# "Agriculture" including only plants and excluding animals

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

In English, "[agriculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture)" includes the cultivation of both plants and animals for food. In some languages, a cognate such as "[*agricultura*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultura)" (in Spanish) may contemplate only plants and exclude animals. What would be the equivalent expression in English -- could it be "crop farming" or "crop agriculture"? Also note: in such languages, a different term exists for the combination of plant and animal cultivation: "[*agropecuaria*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agropecuaria)" (in Spanish).

Comment: 'Crop' is used by the intensive poultry farming industry too. We have 'arable' farming but that is for wheat, barley etc and excludes fruit and vegetables. The word 'vegriculture' does not seem to be used, yet, except as a trading name.

Comment: Horticulture refers to plants, but doesn’t include large-scale, intensive crop farming like wheat.

Comment: Please don't forget about [*fungiculture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungiculture) and [*algaculture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algaculture), which are the farming — the commercial cultivation — of two *other* kingdoms of life that are neither plants nor animals.

Comment: @Xanne - Horticulture refers specifically to garden plants (Latin _hortus_, a garden).

Comment: plant agriculture versus animal agriculture OR animal husbandry.

Answer (score 1):

It seems "plant agriculture" is not unheard of; see, for example:

- ["Department of Plant Agriculture"](https://www.plant.uoguelph.ca/about-us)
- ["Plant agriculture: Readings from Scientific American"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716709961)
- ["Antibiotic Use in Plant Agriculture"](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.phyto.40.120301.093927)
- ["Plant Agriculture" and "Animal Agriculture"](https://www.canr.msu.edu/research/plant-agriculture/)

Besides the ad hoc evidence of usage above, I've also found a [definition](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0014479700023371):

> Plant agriculture concerns the cultivation of useful plants.

The complementing term "animal agriculture" seems well established as a synonym or generalization of ["animal husbandry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_husbandry):

- ["Science of Animal Agriculture"](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=-fQIAAAAQBAJ)
- ["The Science of Animal Agriculture"](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BhNJAAAAYAAJ)
- ["Animal Agriculture: Sustainability, Challenges and Innovations"](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=PiG5DwAAQBAJ)
- ["Animal Agriculture: The Biology, Husbandry, and Use of Domestic Animals"](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bZmPQgAACAAJ)

The usage of both terms over the last century is also confirmed by the Google Books [ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plant%20agriculture%2Canimal%20agriculture&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).